# how to format date on sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Date format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` (27/09/2019 23:59:20) in my DB.

I need to convert into `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (2019-09-27 23:59:20)

How to convert in the query?

I tried to like this query, the output is null

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','28/12/2019 23:59:20') from table;
```

Comment: Are you using sqlite or mongodb?

Comment: sqlite database for caching android

Comment: I remove MongoDB sir

Comment: @BloodLoss just to inform you: the `sql` tag is not wrong for you question if it is followed by `sqlite`. In fact it increases the number of views of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way-

```
select substr('27/09/2019 23:59:20', 7, 4)||'-'||
substr('27/09/2019 23:59:20', 1,2)||'-'||substr('27/09/2019 23:59:20', 4,2)
||substr('27/09/2019 23:59:20',11,9)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(25) 
SET @Date = '2019/09/07  10:12:12.000'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date, 103), 121) Date
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23988955)